# Can't connect a DB to AWS

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm using AWS for my project and Laravel 5. Just installed my laravel project in the EC2 and set up a DB in RDS. I imported the `.sql` file using mysql workbench. In my `.env` I set up the host, the DB name, user and password but when I go to the project in the browser I get an error:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55: 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'blue*****.************.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (4)
```

Put the `*` for security reasons. So what could be wrong?

**Update:**

When I tried to connect to the RDS instance using the command line I got:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'blue****.**********.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
```

Comment: Can you connect to mysql via terminal from your EC2 ?

Comment: Log in to the instance by SSH and type this on the command line: `mysql -u <username> -p -h blue*****.************.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com` and see if that works. If not, update your question with the resulting error.

Comment: When you have an error such as that one, it usually indicates a network or firewall problem. Make sure your instance is allowed to access your RDS instance.

Comment: @datasage I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: @Alex Look at the security group attached to your RDS instance.

Comment: @Joseph Updated the question ;)

Comment: @datasage Do I have to look for the Inbound or Outbound?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to connect to the RDS instance from the EC2 instance has to do with security group.

Before your EC2 instance can communicate with the RDS server, you need to configure a security group for the RDS.

You can check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html) and [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html) for more details.

Comment: There is so much written for these Security Groups and eventually I did not understand how to set them up in order to allow a communication between EC2 and RDS

Comment: You should also make sure that your EC2 and your RDS are in the same VPC, otherwise they won't be able to see each other.